# Insert 2 table data in 1 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working in 2 set of table data in one controller to display in one view to create a pie chart.

The 1st table for the 1st pie chart is perfectly working it. Now in for the 2nd table data to create another pie chart in using asp.net mvc. Doesn't work

[This is the link for the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n0ejgfN_97ikU2tumG3pkCK9SgAZ6-0-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You have to post your code if you want to get some help.

Comment: I've posted a link of file. Thank you!

Comment: @boredeggyolk Please [edit] your question so that your linked code is included as text, not behind a link. Otherwise your question may be closed as it cannot stand on its own.

Comment: My questions is How to declare, get and retrieve data from another table. In my controller I've already declared and retrieve a 1st table data to create a bar chart and pie chart however I want to set another table to create a another pie chart in same view. Thank you!